# java read input from file with multiple data types of varying lengths

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to read from a file containing names and doubles, this would be easy if it was first name, last name then the doubles, but some of the lines have a middle initial and some have just one name. 

**Like this:**

Hancock John 40.00 9.75

Light Karen L 40.00 9.60

Bob 12.02 42.90

and so on
I'm putting the names into a string array and the numbers into a 2d array.
So how would I separate those data types?
EDIT:
I was trying this at first

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.text.*;
   import java.util.*;

   public class JEdwards11 
    {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {  PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("H:/Java/program11.out");
           String filename = "H:/Java/program11.dat", line, fullname;
         StringTokenizer st;
         Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));
         int ctr = 0, i = 0, k = 0;
         String [] names = new String [30];//print vertically
         double [][] money = new double [7][30];//short across, long down
         //hours worked, hourly rate, gross pay, net pay, fed, state, union

            //while(inFile.hasNext())
            for(i=0; i< names.length; i++)
            {


            if(inFile.hasNextDouble())
            {money[1][i] = inFile.nextDouble();
             money[2][i] = inFile.nextDouble();}

            else
            names[i] = inFile.next();

            }


            /*while(inFile.hasNext())
            {line = inFile.nextLine();
            st = new StringTokenizer(line);
            names[i]=st.nextString;
            money[1][i] = st.nextDouble();
            money[2][i] = st.nextDouble();*/

            for(i=0;i<names.length;i++)


            for(i=0; i<names.length; i++)
            System.out.println("name = " + names[i] +" money1 = "+money[1][i]                                                                  +" money2= "+money[2][i]);

            inFile.close();
            outFile.close();

            }

            }
```

which did not work at all. Since then I've searching Google and re-reading my java book. Sorry for the formatting, it's not being cut/paste friendly and last time I hit enter it posted before I was ready :(

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It is often good to add an example of what you have tried to do to figure out your problem on your own.

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression to match the doubles at the end and capture the name using a capture group?

Comment: I'm learning java from a very bad teacher so I'm still new to it; I had to google what regular expressions were, so no I have not tried them. I've been trying to get tokenizers or scanners to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have followed another approach. Anyway I give you one easy trick to solve it with *Scanner*, just add tokens to a buffer until digits are encountered, then assign it to the name array.

Again, your if-else block is erroneous since per iteration either if-part or the else-part will be executed. Try something like this, it will definitely solve your problem :

```
for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        StringBuffer sbr = new StringBuffer();

        while (inFile.hasNext("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
            sbr.append(inFile.next() + " ");
        }
        names[i] = sbr.toString().trim();

        if (inFile.hasNextDouble()) {
            money[1][i] = inFile.nextDouble();
            money[2][i] = inFile.nextDouble();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works far better than anything I tried, however when I use it as it is written now I get blanks, not nulls just empty lines, in every other name[i]. I tried consuming the newline by adding "blank = inFile.nextLine(); after the append, which made the names perfect but now I get no numbers in my 2d array :( Also when I do it the first way the first 2 numbers in my numbers array are 0.00, I assume that is because the when the strings are appended i is incremented before the first values get placed into the 2d array.

Comment: @Jcewazhere : I have edited the answer, have a look. I see you used an additional for loop to print the array, it's unnecessary. Remove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked quite well, and yes the extra for loop was unnecessary, I have removed it. Now I get to bang my head against the other 90% of this program ha. However it should be simply manipulating the arrays which I know how to do pretty well. My trouble was all caused because the input had to have some middle names in it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with Scanner?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_scanner.htm

There's a link, or just google Java.Util.Scanner.

I would init a `Java.Util.Scanner` with the file text, then use calls to `hasNextDouble()` to determine if next token is a double. If so, scan it with `nextDouble`, otherwise treat the next token as part of a name.

```
//psuedo code
Scanner s; // init with file
while ( s.hasNext() )
{
    if ( s.hasNextDouble() )
    {
        double d = s.nextDouble();
        // add to array
    }
    else
    {
        String name = s.next();
        // add to names
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried:
while(inFile.hasNext())
{if(inFile.hasNextDouble())
  {money[1][i] = inFile.nextDouble();
   money[2][i] = inFile.nextDouble();}
  else
    names[i] = inFile.next();
  }
for(i=0; i<names.length; i++)
System.out.println("name = " +names[i] +" money1 = "+money[1][i] +" money2= "+money[2][i]);
and using a for loop but they both gave bad output. Like this:
name = Hancock money1 = 0.0 money2= 0.0
name = John money1 = 0.0 money2= 0.0
name = null money1 = 40.0 money2= 9.75
I get why the names are screwing up, I need some way to stick names together. But I don't get why the numbers are wrong